# How do I name div classes in Bootstrap to edit them in an external CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am currently getting familiar with bootstrap. I have noticed that column divs have specific names which depend on their size; col-xs-4 , col-lg-8, col-md-4 etc.

I cannot seem to find a way to name the divs specifically so that I can edit them through CSS.

If I have 2 col-md-4 for example, and I tried to edit them separately in CSS, they would both be altered because their names are the same.

Comment: Start with learning CSS.... class names, selectors, specificity etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add indiviudal classes to each col-md-4 so you can have specific style elements for each one.

```
<div class="col-md-4 left-style">LEFT</div> 
<div class="col-md-4 right-style">RIGHT</div>
```